# swift NSManagedObject subclass initialization issue

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm making a new app and I deciced to try to develop it in swift.
I'm using CoreData and I've got a strange behavior I guess.

I'm creating a new Item (NSManagedObject subclass) like this :

```
   let managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!

   self.newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Item", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as Item

   self.newItem.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "startDate")
```

when I print the startDate, it is always nil. It is the same with the item's properties (link to other objects).

In the debugger, it seems that the object (newItem) is well instanciated (I see a (myapp.Item!) as the object type), but it seems that the debugger is not really user friendly with CoreData. I found no way of inspecting or printing all the object's properties like it was the case in objectiveC.

Is there something I'm missing here? The instanciation seems quite correct to me no?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you see the object type in the debugger does not mean the object is correctly initialized. It most likely just shows you the type you declared in your class when defining `self.newItem`.

I agree, the Swift debugger has a lot to be desired. You cannot rely on it to debug this situation, unless you want to learn more advanced debugger commands, but the typing is just as much if you insert log statements into your code instead.

Check and confirm that

- your managed object context is not `nil`
- your insert method indeed creates a proper `Item` object which is not `nil`
- your managed object subclass for the `Item` entity is properly configured

Maybe you want to try to first create a new local `Item` variable before assigning it to `self.newItem` to eliminate any ivar errors.

Try to see if anything changes if you save the context.

Try to get used to accessing the attribute with the subclass properties, such as `newItem.startDate` rather than relying on the error-prone `valueForKey` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually it is a bit weirder. When I print the iVar values (using po in the debugger), they are all nil right after I set them. But a few seconds after, it seems that they are filled. Really weird. Is it a swift/CoreData behavior due to compiler/debugger issues?

Comment: Please use `printf` or `NSLog` to check the variables contents.